# by works only inside run/apply

Tags: kotlin, lambda

i'm trying to integrate this library (Kotlin DSL for Mojang's brigadier) into my project: https://github.com/nicolaic/brigadier-dsl

And here's the problem:
for some reason, i can use `by` qualifier with function library provides only while `this` is being  `DslCommandBuilder<*>`

here's what i mean:

```
fun test(builder: DslCommandBuilder<ClientCommandSource>) {
        builder.apply {
            val bar by this.integer("bar") // works
        }
        val bar by builder.integer("bar")
    }
```

My goal is to be able to use syntax library provides inside my arbitrary `execute` function without using `builder.run {}`

```
object SetCommand : Command("set", "allows you to configure module settings") {
    override fun execute(builder: DslCommandBuilder<ClientCommandSource>) {
        // logic
    }
}
```

The only workaround i see is to manually put `builder.run {}` into each and every single one of these `execute` functions

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the difference between your proposed code and [the example](https://github.com/nicolaic/brigadier-dsl#create-and-register-a-command), you're wanting to declare a subclass, vs their use of a dynamic builder pattern.

You might instead declare your own base class (not `Command`), which then does the necessary to construct your class. The use of sealed classes is not necessary, but possibly convenient for other reasons.

```kotlin
sealed class MyCommands<S : Any>(val name: String, val docString: String, val block: DslCommandBuilder<S>.() -> Unit) {
   init {
      val cmd = command<MessageSender>(name, block)
      dispatcher.register(cmd.buildLiteral())
   }

    object Set : MyCommands<TheDslCommandBuilderTypeYouWant>(
        "set",
        "...",
        {
            val input by string("input")
            runs {
                ...
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: did you try ur code tho? I can't use lambda instead of `object Set`'s body like in your code

Comment: @OffeeX - move the code into the parens, as above, revised.